# Permission Denied when executing python file in linux

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi

I am working with my Raspberry Pi 2 B+ and I am using Raspbian. I have a python script located at `/home/pi/Desktop/control/gpio.py`

When I type `/home/pi/Desktop/control/gpio.py` into the command line, I get the message

```
bash: /home/pi/Desktop/control/gpio.py Permission denied
```

I have tried running `sudo -s` before running that command also but that doesnt work. My python script is using the `Rpi.GPIO` library.

If someone could please explain why I am getting this error it would be appreciated!

Comment: go log-in as root, or try renaming your directory or file.. it's file permission ithink

Answer (score 6):

You will get this error because you do not have the `execute` permission on your file. There are two ways to solve it:

1. Not executing the file in the first place. By running `python gpio.py` python will load the file by reading it, so you don't need to have execute permission.
2. Granting yourself execute permission. You do this by running `chmod u+x yourfile.py`.

   However, doing so will not work unless you add a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) at the top of your python program. It will let your linux know which interpreter it should start. For instance:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env python
   ```

   This would try to run `python` using your current `$PATH` settings. If you know which python you want, put it here instead.

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/python3
   ```

   Remember the shebang must be the very first line of your program.

Comment: This is the way. Surprising that as `root` I am not granted permission to every file in the system, hahaha.

Comment: @FaithReaper> for files, as long as suid/sgid bits aren't set too, execute bit is more of a convenience than an actual access control. In fact, you can run a program with only read permission, by passing it to `ld.so`. For instance on my system: `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /bin/ls` runs ls, regardless of its execute bit. And at worst if you can read the binary you could always copy it and set execute bit on your copy. So… once you take it as convenience, it follows that this simply lets root use that convenience as well.

Answer (score 1):

do like this maybe work:

```
cd /home/pi/Desktop/control/  
python gpio.py
```

Because `gpio.py` is not a executable file, you should `run` it by `python` instead

Comment: chmod +x gpio.py      for sure it will be executable?

Comment: I've tried this before, maybe not work,either. It would not be treated as a python file, and lead to an error like "import: command not found"

Answer (score 0):

In my case, to run [sticky](https://github.com/linuxmint/sticky) (a program for *sticky notes* in python), on *Linux Fedora*, I had to `chown` the `executable` and the files (`.py` and `.css`) linked to it:

```
sudo chown my_user:my_user /usr/bin/sticky
sudo chown my_user:my_user -R /usr/lib/sticky/
sudo chown my_user:my_user -R /usr/share/sticky/
```

Otherwise, the received errors were:

```
python: can't open file '/usr/lib/sticky/sticky.py': [Errno 13] Permission denied

gi.repository.GLib.GError: gtk-css-provider-error-quark: sticky.css:1:0Failed to import: Error opening file /usr/share/sticky/sticky.css: Permission denied
```

In this way I'm able to run `sticky` without `sudo`.